# CSS/HTML: Have text at left side

Tags: html, css

```
<span style='float: left; margin: 10px; width: 60px; display: block;'>
<img style='border: 1px solid #FFF; width: 61px; height: 80px;' src='images/profilePhoto/thumbs/86.jpg'>
<br>
<a href='profil.php?id=86'>Megan F.</a>
<br><br>
</span>
<div style='margin-left: 90px;'>
<h1>(inget ämne)</h1>
<div>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec fringilla urna eget urna euismod aliquet. Duis porta volutpat blandit. Phasellus bibendum bibendum porta. Nunc molestie tristique leo, sed euismod orci ultricies vitae. Mauris non libero a leo ultricies laoreet. Suspendisse luctus urna vel sapien tristique vitae semper nulla eleifend. Integer congue aliquam pharetra. Phasellus diam neque, tincidunt vel elementum vel, ornare sit amet mi. Nulla tincidunt purus in odio vulputate mollis. Nunc urna odio, rutrum eu ultricies a, facilisis ullamcorper nunc. In purus velit, varius vel laoreet eu, tincidunt non purus. Nulla facilisi. Sed ac lectus nibh. Praesent non velit nibh.<br />
... 
</div>
```

This is what i have right now for this:
[image: http://img192.imageshack.us/img192/7857/applytext.png]

How can i apply text there like showed in the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the new text to be vertically aligned with the second paragraph, then you add a

```
<div style="clear: both"></div>
```

before the second paragraph, and then do another float like you did originally.

If you just want to float a whole panel at the left, then you would just add it to the floated content.  But looks like your new text is vertically aligned with the second paragraph, so the method listed above would be it.

Comment: I just want to float a whole panel at the left, should i just add the "text" to the floated content and do <br><br><br><br> to under or is there a nicer method

Comment: usually, use a `margin-top: 60px` or `margin-top: 6em` to do the spacing instead of using `<br>` is best

Comment: But i have the image and username inside the floated content. And after this, i want it to go 40px down and then have text there.. margin:top on the element will move the image down too